# Illegal start of terms

Tags: prolog

I have written a function all_names in prolog that should seem to work fine:

```
all_names([],[]):- !.
all_names(node(A,_,_),A):- !.
all_names(L,N):- maplist(all_names,L,N).
```

but when running the code below, I receive and illegal start of terms error. Thanks

```
all_names([],Ns),!,Ns=[]).
```

The error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal start of term
ERROR: all_names([],Ns),!,Ns=[]
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: ) .
```

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced and Prolog is even telling you that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a reasonable error message. The final closing bracket doesn't have an matching open one.

Running `all_names([],Ns),!,Ns=[].` works fine for me.